# Can I use any brand led digital display (18 pin) to replace a part for a control board in a washing machine?

Tags: led, digital-logic, 7segmentdisplay

I am replacing a control board in a washing machine. The replacement parts do not have the led 2 digit display part attached. Can I use any brand of digital display as long as the pins match up. The spot on the control board is for an 18 pin 2 digit led display.

Comment: Brand doesn't matter, just make sure it's the right pinout. Do you know what it expects?

Comment: How do you know if it works even after attaching the display? There might be other components missing, or the board software may have display support turned off.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use any brand of digital display as long as the pins match up.

The pins might match up but the orientation of the LEDs may be reversed. You'll need to figure out if they are common anode or common cathode and replace with the correct part.

[image]

*Figure 1. Standard 7-segment display layout and segment identification. The decimal, if supplied, point requires an eight LED.*

[image]

*Figure 2. As might be expected, package pin-count is reduced by using a common pin for one side of all the LEDs. In this case a common anode is used.*

[image]

*Figure 3. A common cathode display. These have the advantage that, for multiplexed displays, the digit can be strobed using an NPN transistor in the cathode connection to ground.*

You can test quite safely with a 5 V PSU and a 1 kΩ series resistor to determine polarity.

*Images source and further reading: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/display-technology/7-segment-display-basics/) (mine).*

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.lumex.com/spec/LDD-C512RI.pdf) is a typical datasheet for an 18-pin 2-digit display. You need to make sure it's the proper "polarity", common-anode or common cathode, even if the pinouts match.

[image]

There will be other differences such as character height, color and brightness at a given current, but appliance manufacturers tend to use pretty generic parts for cost and availability reasons and chances are a similar substitute will work acceptably well (might not match other displays in brightness though).

You may or may not be able to find a datasheet for the one in your unit, but if even you can't you can remove the display from the PCB and probe it out with a 5V supply and 1K resistor in series.